# Why can't I use the R2D2 tag?

Tags: support, tags

When I try to use the tag `R2D2` I get the error:

[image]

> You are attempting to create the tag [r2-d2]; however the tag [r2-d2] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

First of all, I'm not trying to use the hyphenated tag. I'm just trying to use `R2D2`.

Second - when I try to use the hyphenated tag - I get the same error!

My question is: **Why can't I use the R2D2 tag?**

Comment: Are you saying this site has tags that are specifically disallowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you *should* be able to use this tag. It's been added to the system and shows up in the tag list. Specifically, [r2-d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2-d2) exists as a tag and [r2d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2d2) is a synonym that should automatically remap to [r2-d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2-d2).

I have no idea why the site won't let you use it. I suspect the combination of having a tag synonym but not being on any questions is confusing the software somehow.

The good news is you *shouldn't* be using it. It looks like the tag has been cleaned out -- removed from all questions -- in the hopes that it would fade into obscurity. It's a bad tag; character tags in general aren't something we like to encourage.

Comment: Currently, [tag:r2-d2] has no synonyms, which makes this answer not completely correct.

Answer (score 2):

What [Jake Gould](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7803/3804)  said is correct,  there should be no need for such a specfic tag.

However,  I think the system sees `r2d2` and `r2-d2` as the same,  as far as I know.  It will prevent duplicates based on this.

Comment: r2d2 is listed as a synonym for r2-d2 so the system clearly knows they're different...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I think it could be a glitch, where it thinks two conflicting things at once.